# how to get latitude and longitude value in BroadcastReceiver service?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, broadcastreceiver

So i made an app which will run if the power button of the phone pressed 5 time the app will execute something like open url in Background. Now the problem is i want extract latitude and longitude value in that time. 
code is

LockService class

```
public class LockService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LockService getService() {
            return LockService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

ScreenReceiver

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    static int countPoweroff =0;

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;
    int lol;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        Log.e("LOB","onReceive");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here

            wasScreenOn = false;
            countPoweroff++;
            Log.e("LOB",""+countPoweroff);
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            if (countPoweroff == 3){
                Log.e("LOB","userpresent");
                Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
                String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                context.startActivity(i);

                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                } else {
                    //deprecated in API 26
                    vibrator.vibrate(500);
                }
                countPoweroff =0;

            }
            wasScreenOn = true;

        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){




        }
    }
```

Run service in main activity

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));
```

I have used basic Locationmanager code in main activity which works only when the activity open.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that you put in an activity is of course going to be executed only when the activity is running. If your location manager is in activity and the activity is not running, then you can't get location. Your bus won't move anywhere when the driver turned off the engine and went to a lunch break. Doing anything that is unrelated to Ux in an activity is a bad design. I don't know the detail of your implementation, hence, it is difficult to say anything more.You should implement the location manager in a service and send result to the activity using Callable or CompletableFuture.

Comment: There are so many app in google app store where the app have feature like you press the power button 5 time or you shakes your phone and the app will send text to emergency number with location coordinate without open the app, I mean app in running in background and execute those task, i want to do the same.

Comment: Then in that case, they are getting the location in a background service that is running at all times even when the app is not opened by the user. Another point is, remember service runs of the main thread, hence, you have to explicitly create a worker thread to do location gathering, as it might lock the main thread in poor GPS or network location scenarios.